# My program doesn't compilem, can anyone help me where should I fix

Tags: arrays, c, csv

I am trying to read csv file in an array. And also change the values of csv file from c program.

I try to use struct to store the variables. While compiling the program there is an error in the `strtok`, `strcpy` which says unsafe function.

This is the error while printing in another function

> Error C2371 'printValues': redefinition; different basic type

My code:

```
typedef struct key_value
{
    char name[100];
    int price;
    int zaiko;
}dict;

    ...
    dict values[999];
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(buff, 1024, fp))
    {
        field_count = 0;
        row_count++;
        if (row_count == 1)
            continue; 

        char* field = strtok(buff, ",");
        while (field)
        {
            if (field_count == 0)
                strcpy(values[i].name, field);
            if (field_count == 1)
                strcpy(values[i].price, field);
            if (field_count == 2)
                strcpy(values[i].zaiko, field);

            field = strtok(NULL, ",");
            field_count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printValues(values);
    return 0;
}

void printValues(dict values[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
    {
        printf("Name--->%s, price---->%d, zaiko---->%d\n",
            values[i].name, values[i].price, values[i].zaiko);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the exact error(s). Also, `strcpy(values[i].price, field);` is wrong, you can't copy a string to an `int`. Use [`atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) or (safer) [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) instead.

Comment: void printValues(dict values[])
{
 for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
 {
  printf("Name--->%s, price---->%d, zaiko---->%d\n",
   values[i].name, values[i].price, values[i].zaiko);
 }
}

this is the error while printing in another function
Error C2371 'printValues': redefinition; different basic types

Comment: If it is your intention to convert a string to an `int`, you cannot use `strcpy` for that. You can use the functions [`atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) and [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) for that. The function `strtol` has better error handling, so I recommend that function. But `atoi` is a bit easier to use.

Comment: @GurungBuddha: Important information such as the error message should go into the question itself. Please [edit] the question and delete your comment afterwards.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel ok thank you

Comment: @GurungBuddha please [edit] your question and tell us what is `printValues` is and _where_ it appears in your code? Read about this: [mcve].

Comment: @Jabberwocky i cannot write more codes in the question

Comment: @GurungBuddha then show only the relevant parts, _where_ is `printvalues` and where and how do you call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printValues` is used before it is declared.

You can:

- either put the `printValues` *before* the function where you're calling it.
- or put the forward declaration of `void printValues(dict values[]);` before you're using it.

Example of forward declaration:

```
void printValues(dict values[]);   // forward declaration

...

void SomeFunction()
{
   ...
   printValues(values);
   ...
}

void printValues(dict values[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
    {
        printf("Name--->%s, price---->%d, zaiko---->%d\n",
            values[i].name, values[i].price, values[i].zaiko);
    }
}
```

---

Assuming you're using Visual Studio:

In order to get rid of the "unsafe function" errors: put this at the very top of your code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```